# How to know if an URL is relative or absolute in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I'm trying to do the following in Jekyll:

- I have an URL;
- This URL can be relative ("/media/image.jpg") or absolute "http://example.com/image.jpg";
- If the URL is relative I have to append to its beginning my site domain ("http://my-site/media/image.jpg"). If don't, nothing changes.

Sadly I have no clue yet on how to achieve this.

I'd love if somebody could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using liquid. Here is a basic example of what you could do. You will probably want to adjust it for your own use.

```
{% assign myurl = "/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}
{% if myurl contains '://' %}
{{myurl}}
{% else %}
{{ myurl | prepend: site.url }}
{% endif %}
```

**Breaking down the code:**

This line just creates a variable holding the url:

```
{% assign myurl = "/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}
```

Next, we will check if the url is absolute. This simple version does that by checking the string, `://`, is in the url:

```
{% if myurl contains '://' %}
```

If the url does, liquid will simply print out the url variable:

```
{{myurl}}
```

If not, liquid will prepend the site's url to the beginning of url and print the complete url:

```
{% else %}
{{ myurl | prepend: site.url }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You, Sir, are a genius!

Do you know how can I make a "if not contains"?

Comment: Ok, suddenly I remembered about the 'unless' block. Thank you very much!